# How to merge multiple Tiff files into one page tiff file?

Tags: .net, itext

I have a requirement to create a single page tiff file by merging multiple tiff files through itextsharp. till now i only get multi-page tiff files. I there a way create it ?

Comment: As far as I know, iText doesn't create TIFF files, so I am assuming that your question is about converting TIFF to PDF.

Comment: can it be done by easypdf ?

Comment: That's an off-topic question. See bullet 4 in the [StackOverflow FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using iText 5, then you will find the [PagedImages](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-10#402-pagedimages.java) example in "iText in Action". You tagged the question as a .Net question, so instead of copy/pasting that Java example, I'll copy/past the C# version of that example:

```
public void AddTif(Document document, String path) {
  RandomAccessFileOrArray ra = new RandomAccessFileOrArray(path);
  int n = TiffImage.GetNumberOfPages(ra);
  Image img;
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    img = TiffImage.GetTiffImage(ra, i);
    img.ScaleToFit(523, 350);
    document.Add(img);
  }
}
```

If you are using iText 7, I can only give you the Java example for now (the documentation is still under development). You will find plenty of information about Image support in [Chapter 3 of "iText 7: Building Blocks"](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-3-using-ileafelement-implementations). Search for the [iText 7 "PagedImages"](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/examples/chapter-3#1937-c03e19_pagedimages.java) example.

**Important:**

These examples explain how to create a PDF from one or more TIFF files with one or more pages. If you really want to create a TIFF file using iText, you are using the wrong tool. iText nor iTextSharp create TIFF files.

Comment: can it be made by easypdf ?

Comment: That's an off-topic question. See bullet 4 in the [StackOverflow FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: am just sharing a thought that if it is done by adding easypdf in project ?

Comment: I don't know easypdf, so how would I know. Have you contacted the people at easypdf?